# Fabric (crashlyitcs plugin) not responding

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I have had this problem for a while, When running an app using crashlytics framework. I have tried reinstalling the plugin to no effect. It stalls my computer after a while and nothing responds properly.

[image]

Comment: It's an app, not a plugin, isn't it?

Comment: I think it was advertised by Crashlytics as a plugin?

Comment: Fair enough; a bit misleading of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

solved the problem by removing folders: 
~ / Library / Caches / com.crashlytics.data 
~ / Library / Caches / com.crashlytics.mac

Comment: it may only be temporary I had the issue again. Crashlytics are working on a beta fix which should be with us shortly I will keep you posted